# UNION ALL takes forever with NULL dataset

Tags: sql, oracle11g

On a query like:

```
select col_A from t1
UNION ALL
select col_A from t2
```

were `select col_A from t2` return **zero** rows, Oracle 11G is taking forever to run. If t2 returns at least 1 row, this query is at least 10 times faster. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oracle 11 has issues with nulls in unions. Either `NVL()` or restrict the query to remove `NULL`s

Comment: there are no predicates on either query in your real world case? If not, then perhaps t2 is being populated with lots of rows which are then subsequently deleted without clearing the table's HWM (high water mark), meaning that Oracle has to scan a whole load of empty blocks before it can determine there are no rows?

Comment: @JohnHC have you got a link to something with proof for that claim, please? Also, in the OP's case, it's a UNION ALL, which (IMHO) shouldn't have any problems regardless of whether the column is null or not, since it's simply appending the second result set to the first.

Comment: @Boneist Personal experience... But yes, `union all` should have resolved that, so maybe not applicable in OP's case

Comment: @Boneist Yes, in our real word case, we have a lot of predicates both under t2 query as well as after the `union all`. Also we are not sourcing direct tables, we are actually using `WITH()` clauses 

@JohnHC Could you please provide me an example for using `NVL` to work around a 0 rows return? Thanks for all the effort :)

Comment: @JohnHC - What does "**zero** rows" have to do with `NULL`s? (Answer: Nothing whatsoever.)

Comment: @Fdiang - what makes you think the problem is caused by the second member of `union all` returning zero rows? That is almost surely **not** the reason. Did you take a look at the execution plans for your queries? What do they show?

Comment: @mathguy Yeh, I realised that after answering, but I'm leaving it there for an irrelevant observation

Comment: @JohnHC I just ran my own very simple test, having all null records had no effect on the speed with which I received my results, it was lightening fast. I did this both in SQL*Plus and in TOAD.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm having the same issue, trying to UNION two sets from CTEs. Individually they take seconds, but in the UNION it takes over a minute. I don't have privs for explain plan, but I got rid of NULLS and its still slow. I'm stuck.