# ORACLE Command is taking forever when using UNION ALL

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, insert, union-all

I am currently trying to create nice and fast running SQL commands and found something I cannot explain yet.

**The SQL code that causes problems:**

```
INSERT INTO FIELD_TYPE (FIELD_TYPE_ID, FIELD_VALUE_TYPE_ID, CREATOR)
SELECT :p0, :p1, :p2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT :p3, :p4, :p5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT :p6, :p7, :p8 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0
```

**Explanation:**

`FIELD_TYPE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL` (PK)

`FIELD_VALUE_TYPE NUMBER NOT NULL`

`CREATOR NUMBER NOT NULL` (FK)

**My Question:**

My C# Application gets an array of items to insert. For each item I add a `SELECT` and a `UNION ALL` as shown above.
The last step is adding a `SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0` to have no syntax errors when no item to insert was passed to the method.

In the case of not adding the selection of the emtpy set, everything works like a charm. 
As soon as I add the selection of the emtpy set, the execution of the command takes forever. My first guess is that the usage of `NULL` could be a problem, but I am not entirely sure.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Can I avoid this in a smart way?
The code shown above is generated in a base class that does not know about the column types of the table to insert into. This makes it quite difficult to figure out default values to use instead of `NULL` if this is the reason of my problem.

I use is the ORACLE Managed DataAccess (ODP) from NuGet and a ORACLE 11g DB.

**Common answers that won't help me :)**

- Use an ORM Framework

Comment: In the meanwhile I found a solution for the problem in my application: If the are no item there is no need to execute a query. Still i really wanna know what went wrong here :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105606/union-all-takes-forever-with-null-dataset?rq=1 seems to make an identical complaint, and there are a few unqualified "oracle11g is bad with nulls" comments..